# Seaborn get_xticklabels return empty text

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Construct histogram using the `histplot`

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g=sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True)
```

[image]

I would like to extract the xticklabels

```
ticks = [i.get_text () for i in g.get_xticklabels ()]
```

However, the `ticks` return empty list

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

[image]

May I know how to extract the xticklabel

```
[170,180,190,200,210,220,230]
```

Comment: I tried your code and works for me ticks is ['160', '170', '180', '190', '200', '210', '220', '230', '240']. If it could be useful my seaborn version in '0.11.1'

Comment: Hi @r-beginners, without the list comprehension, your suggestion return `[Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, '')]`

Comment: Hi @solopiu, Mine is __version__ = "0.11.1". Im using Pycharm on Ubuntu

Comment: i can't reproduce either with 0.11.1 seaborn. what about `matplotlib.__version__` ?

Comment: Hi @tdy , Im using matplotlib: 3.4.2

Comment: Hi @solopiu, do you mind share your matplotlib version. Thanks

Comment: @balandongiv my matplotlib version is 3.3.2

Comment: with sns 0.11.1 and matplotlib 3.4.2, i get `['160', '170', '180', '190', '200', '210', '220', '230', '240']`

Comment: @balandongiv I tried in another environment in which I have 3.4.2 version of matplotlib and I have your same problem. Though with g.get_xticks() I obtain the numbers

Comment: Hi @solopiu, `g.get_xticks()` does the job, appreciate it. You can share this as answer thou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `g.get_xticks()`. I tried it with both `matplotlib` version `3.3.2` and `3.4.2`

Comment: I don't see how this works... get_xticks() returns a list of "xaxis' tick locations in data coordinates" according to the matplotlib docs. So no info about **ticklabels** is returned... My matplotlib is also 3.4.3. I am also getting an empty list when calling get_xticklabels()... The matplotlib docs are unfathomably useless in this regard.